# Restrict a cost conversion in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, textview

I have entered a value to my database as **$1000000000**. it stored in Database also its looks like as same. when retrieve it from using the DB. Its converted to **$1e+09** automatically. how to restrict it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What API, what function exactly are you calling, on which object, to retrieve the value? How did you define your table?

Comment: i have defined it as a Double value. showing it in a `textview`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.000.000.000 is equal to 1e+09, the only difference is that the second is value is *printed* in scientific notation. You said, that the database field holds the value in it's "standard" form.

I assume, you get the value and store it in a float (Float) or double (Double) field/variable. Now if you convert that number to a String you can use the [`Formatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class to choose between scientific and non-scientific representation:

```
double value = 1000000000.;
String scientific = String.format("%f", value);
String nonScientific = String.format("%e", value);
String automatic = String.format("%g", value);
```

---

Hint - if you have a currency output and want to restrict the precision, try

```
System.out.printf("Price: $%.2f", value);
```